# PHP is_file() not work correctly

Tags: php

I want to check files in directory and i'm using `scandir()`and `is_file()` for check. In this simple code `is_file()` return `false` for me. but in directory I have 3 file.

```
$files = scandir('uploads/slideShow');
$sfiles = array();
foreach($files as $file) {
  if( is_file($file) ) {
    $sfiles[] = $file;
    // echo $file;
  }
}
```

result for `scandir()` with `$file`s variable:

```
Array
(
  [0] => .
  [1] => ..
  [2] => 6696_930.jpg
  [3] => 9_8912141076_L600.jpg
  [4] => untitled file.txt
)
```

result for `$sfiles`:

```
Array
(
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `scandir` returns just the filename, so your code is looking for `untitled file.txt` et al in the *current* directory, not the scanned one.

This is in contrast to `glob("uploads/slideShow/*")`, which will returns the full path to the files you're looking at. If you use this `glob` with `is_file`, it should work fine.

Answer (score 5):

that's beacuse you check if it's a file in the current dir, while the files reside in another dir... Try this:

```
$files = scandir('uploads/slideShow');
// ...
foreach($files as $file) {
    if ( is_file('uploads/slideShow/'. $file) ) {
        // file found!
    }
}
```